# Add JLabel on JPanel - BorderLayout

Tags: java, swing, panel, jlabel, border-layout

I want to create a Pong game with a moving ball and all the stuff. I'm now working on my score Labels that I want to add on each side of the center line. One label for the computer score and an other for the player score. The problem is that my panel is set to the BorderLayout. I don't know how i can add my panel to that location.

here is my constructor code :

```
 * Constructor : PlayPanel.java
 */
// ==============================================
public PlayPanel() {
    super(new BorderLayout());
    setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

    panPlayer1 = new JPanel();
    panComputer = new JPanel();

    padPlayer1 = new JPanel();
    padComputer = new JPanel();

    padPlayer1.setPreferredSize(PADPANEL_SIZE);
    padComputer.setPreferredSize(PADPANEL_SIZE);

    panPlayer1.setBackground(PAN_PLAY);
    panComputer.setBackground(PAN_PLAY);

    panPlayer1.add(padPlayer1);
    panComputer.add(padComputer);

    add(panPlayer1, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(panComputer, BorderLayout.EAST);

    player1Score.setFont(FONT_SCORE);
    ComputerScore.setFont(FONT_SCORE);

    // Add them to each side if the line !?!?!?!?!?!?
    add(player1Score);
    add(ComputerScore);

    addMouseMotionListener(this);

    panPlayer1.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent arg0) {
            setPanPanelWidth(arg0.getComponent().getSize().width);
            setPanPanelHeight(arg0.getComponent().getSize().height);
        }

    });

    addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent arg0) {

            setPlayPanelWidth(arg0.getComponent().getSize().width);
            setPlayPanelHeight(arg0.getComponent().getSize().height);
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Add them both to a 1 row, 2 column `GridLayout` and then add that to `BorderLayout.NORTH` of your 
   main panel
2. Incorporate them into your  `playerPanel` and `ComputerPanel` objects.  (I would also re-case the `ComputerPanel` to be `computerPanel`).

Comment: yeah i tried that before but i want them to be on my playScreen, don't wnat them to be in another panel. :|

Comment: You do understand you can nest JPanels, right? Option 1 will do that, and they will be on your PlayPanel. In option 2, also quite viable, you would perhaps do something like this: panPlayer1.add(player1Score, BorderLayout.EAST); (or NORTH?) or use absolute positioning on panPlayer1.